# Covariance matrix and positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $x$ is a $n\times 1$ vector of random variables each of which has a finite second moment. Let
$$
\mu=E(x),\quad V=E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)'].
$$
Then, $V$ is positive semidefinite. I'm wondering whether the converse is true:

> if $V$, dimension $n\times n$, is positive semidefinite, must there exist some $n\times 1$ random vector for which $E(xx')=V$?

That is, I'm wondering if being the covariance matrix of a real random vector imposes any other property other than positive semidefiniteness.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be some mutually orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lVert v_k \rVert^2 = n\lambda_k \geq 0$ then what is the covariance matrix of the set $\{\pm v_k \mid k=1, \ldots, n\}$ of $2n$ elements? What are its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Just to confirm whether I'm understanding you, in your example, $x$ is uniform on the set $\{\pm v_k,k=1,\ldots,n\}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2n}$ each?

Comment: @yurnero Yes, that was intended.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. For that $x$, the covariance matrix $V$ is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nv_kv_k'$ with eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ and eigenvectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. Let $w_k=v_k/\sqrt{n\lambda_k}$ so that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nv_kv_k'=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kw_kw_k'$ so to reverse the process with some starting $V$, I write $V=W\Lambda W'$ where $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and $W$ is orthogonal. Then the $w_k$'s are the columns of $W$, and $v_k=\sqrt{n\lambda_k}w_k$. Is this right?